# To find a integer without a pair in a sequence of integers

Tags: c++

The problem is to find an integer without it's pair in a sequence of integers. Here's what I wrote so far, to me it looks like it should work but it doesn't. Any help for a noob programmer?

```
using namespace std;
int lonelyinteger(vector < int > a, int _a_size) {

for (int i = 0; i < _a_size; i++)
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (int n = i + 1; n < _a_size; n++)
    {
        if (a.at(i) == a.at(n))
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == false)
    {
        return a.at(i);

    }
}
return 0;
}
```

For the input `1 1 2` it outputs `1` while it's supposed to `2`
for `0 0 1 2 1` it outputs `0` and here it has to be `2`

Comment: Please describe how it doesn't work.  For example, provide an input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: you provided the actual output, but not the expected output. It really helps answering if we know **exactly** what your problem is.

Comment: What's the "pair" of an integer? Or are you trying to find distinct numbers in a collection?

Comment: @doctorlove it's exact match in a given array

Comment: With your current approach your inner loop searches from the current position to the end of the array, but you need to also search back to the start of the array as well.

Comment: @CássioRenan the expected output in both cases was supposed to be 2

Comment: Also please pass vectors by reference. And your algorithm would be a lot more efficient if you sorted the vector first.

Comment: @JonathanPotter in fact, it more usual to send in `begin` and `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your inner loop only checks from the index `i` and onward for a duplicate. In the case `1 1 2` the first loop encounters `a[1]` which is `1`. After that index, there is no element that is equal to `1`, so the function returns `1`.

In general, there is a better solution to this problem. Instead of going through the vector twice, you can use a set to keep track of all the elements you have already encountered. For each element, check if the set already contains it. If not, add it to the set. Otherwise, remove it from the set. Anything remaining in the set will be unique within the vector.

Comment: Another approach would be to use the suggestion by @JonathonPotter -- to sort the vector first. Then, if `a[i] != 'a[i+1]`, you got your answer. You have to make sure that you don't access `a` out of bounds when you use that approach.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see how your approach using sets will work without further work needed to be done.  What do you do with the vector of unique values once you get them so as to obtain the "lonely" value?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think you may have read the question like I did originally. It seems that the question is asking about adjacent integers, but it's not. It is actually asking about finding the unique integer in a sequence. Using a set, one can easily determine the unique integer in a sequence. The only elements in the set will be those that were added, but not removed.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers are good.

Now, assume that the array *cannot* be sorted, here is a somewhat lazy approach using `std::map`, but shows what can be done using the various algorithm functions.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int lonelyinteger(const std::vector<int>& a) 
{
    typedef std::map<int, int> IntMap;
    IntMap theMap;  

    // build the map
    for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](int n){ theMap[n]++; });

    // find the first entry with a count of 1
    return 
       find_if(theMap.begin(), theMap.end(),
       [](const IntMap::value_type& pr){return pr.second == 1; })->first;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> TestVect = { 1, 1, 2 };
    cout << lonelyinteger(TestVect);
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/0t89Ni

This code assumes that

1. the passed in vector is not empty,
2. the first item found with a count of `1` is the lonely value.
3. There is at least one "lonely value".

I also changed the signature to take a vector by reference and not send the count (since a vector knows its own size).

The code does not do any hand-coded loops, so that is one source of error removed.

Second, the count of the number of times a number is seen is more or less, done by the map using `operator[]` to insert new entries, and `++` to increase the count on the entry.

Last, the search for the first entry with only a count of 1 is done with `std::find_if`, again guaranteeing success (given that the data follows the assumptions made above).

So basically, without really trying hard, a solution can be written using algorithm functions and usage of the `std::map` associative container.

If your data will consist of multiple (or even no) "lonely" integers, the following changes can be made:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

std::vector<int> lonelyinteger(const std::vector<int>& a) 
{
    std::vector<int> retValue;
    typedef std::map<int, int> IntMap;
    IntMap theMap;  

    // build the map
    for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](int n){ theMap[n]++; });

    // find all entries with a count of 1
    for_each(theMap.begin(), theMap.end(),
       [&](const IntMap::value_type& pr)
            {if (pr.second == 1) retValue.push_back(pr.first); });

    // return our answer
    return retValue;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> TestVect = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 2, 8 };
    std::vector<int> ans = lonelyinteger(TestVect);
    copy(ans.begin(), ans.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," ")); 
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/40NY4k

Note that we now retrieve any entries with an item of 1, and store it in a vector that will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer might be to just sort the lists and then look for something which has a different value before and after it..

Your problem is that the last item of any given value in the list has no subsequent duplicate values and you are thinking having no subsequent duplicates is the same as having no duplicates (which is false).

If you don't want to remove values your inner look has seen and earlier identified as a duplicate of a "previous" value loop over all values in the inner loop ignoring the match with itself.